# Python String manipulation to store result in a string after removing comma delimiter

Tags: python, string, split, substring, python-2.6

I have a string which I want to separate based on the ',' delimiter and store the result in a new string. Currently the split function stores the result in an array. How to store the result in a string with out the ',' delimiter? Also , I want to manipulate the positions of the string content. Are there ways in Python to do this?

code

```
string_in = "a,bcd,e1,20"
print (string_in.split())
```

output

```
['a,bcd,e1,20']
```

I want the below result to be stored in a string without the comma delimiter and manipulate the position of the string content as below.

```
   string_out = a bcd 20 e1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass your delimiter as an argument to split, like so:

```py
>>> split = string_in.split(",")
['a', 'bcd', 'e1', '20']
```

That will give you a list of elements that you can manipulate as you wish. When you want to put them back into a space delimited string, you use `join` like so:

```py
>>> " ".join(split)
'a bcd e1 20'
```

Take a look at the python documentation for `split` and `join`:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel. In your case ordinary search /replace in source string suffices

```
string_in = "a,bcd,e1,20"
result = string_in.replace(',', ' ')
```

If you want split/join then

```
string_in = "a,bcd,e1,20"
result = ' '.join(string_in.split(','))
```

Comment: How can i get the output to be as below? For instance to interchange the last 2 elements. 
a bcd 20 e1

Comment: Oh, missed manipulation step. Then using list is easier if you are going to change elements ir their order